# Союз на границе частей СП

Tags: бсп

> Придет из-за нашего шума повариха — значит (,) мы получим нагоняй!

Comment: Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит.   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220  Этот Справочник - не сетевой мусор.

Comment: И здесь бессоюзное предложение. а не сложноподчиненное ЕСЛИ...ТО

Comment: Принятый ответ неверный!

Comment: Да, принятый ответ неверный.  Вот издание, которое рекомендует Грамота.ру http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?alpha=З  Первое издание вышло в 2012 году, рукопись просматривал Лопатин В.В.  Словарь Фрамполя 2009 года, и его некоторые статьи устарели. ЗНАЧИТ. Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЙ части предложения.  ЗНАЧИТ обособляется даже в функции союза.

Comment: @Sharon Я сайтам как-то не доверяю...

Comment: Вы имеете в виду Грамота. ру? Это основной ресурс, которым пользуются все. http://gramota.ru/  Ему-то как раз и нужно доверять в первую очередь,  Там все материалы постоянно обновляется, он в первую очередь связан с академическими кругами.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я больше склоняюсь все же к тому варианту.

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна, Мы отвечаем, конечно,  вам, но у форума большая аудитория. Нас читают очень многие, и ответы через час уже можно найти в Сети. И мы заинтересованы в том, чтобы это были правильные ответы. (Поэтому принятие ответа —  это тоже ответственное дело.)  Вопрос этот непростой, даже лингвисты решают его по-разному. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПУНКТУАЦИИ — не какой-то там сайт, а серьезная литература. Книга издана  в 2012 году (у меня есть ее бумажная версия), а в Сети электронный вариант.

Comment: Издание одобрено АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИМИ кругами, в том числе Лопатиным В.В., и это наиболее позднее издание, оно ближе к современной точке зрения, чем справочник Фрамполя. Мы только что закончили обсуждать этот вопрос в другой теме, где участники были за то, чтобы ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ вводное слово по Справочнику 2012 года. Всегда лучше в принятии решений ориентироваться на официальное мнение, и его можно использовать для ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВА своей правоты. А вот ссылка на другие учебные ресурсы вам мало в этом поможет. В конечном итоге, мы уважаем любое ваше решение, а все сказанное — это просто ИНФОРМАЦИЯ.

Comment: Справочник Фрамполя можно скачать здесь  https://obuchalka.org/20230103150665/trudnosti-russkoi-punktuacii-slovar-vvodnih-slov-sochetanii-i-predlojenii-opit-slovarya-spravochnika-ostroumova-o-a-frampol-o-d-2009.html

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна http://gramota.ru/ — это государственный проект. Над ним работают учёные. Это самый авторитетный сайт. О ресурсе: http://gramota.ru/gramota/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Конечно нет.** Запятая ли стоит, тире ли, — в любом случае "значит" остается частью двойного союза и **не является вводным**!!!

> Невводное, употребляется как часть двойного подчинительного союза
> «если... значит» в сложных предложениях  с придаточным условия, не
> обособляется: Если уж Калмыков заговорил о женщине в столь
> возвышенном стиле вместо  обычных полублатных банальностей, значит
> матушка была  и впрямь чудо (Ю.Нагибин).

---

P.S. Не надо искать "сетевой мусор". Используйте только узкоспециализированные справочники, например этот:
*Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации.
Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений. Опыт словаря-справочника. М.: Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 502 с.*

Comment: Спасибо. Я прочитала!

Comment: А вы уверены в правильности выбора?

Comment: Для размышлений: Правила орфографии и пунктуации, которыми должны руководствоваться все пишущие на русском языке, были приняты почти 70 лет назад — в 1956 году. С того времени язык изменился, **изменения в правописании фиксировались в многочисленных справочниках, а официальные и общеобязательные правила постепенно устаревали**.